# Xcode 12.4 storyboard can not change background color of a View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, storyboard

I'm a newbie in IOS development and I made a new Iphone app. Try to change in storyboard the background color of a View but can not. I changed it in Inspector pane in Background and Tint block but anyway the colour is black. Even if I change the light mode to light or dark. And therefore the elements are invisible. What I already tried:

1. Deleted a View, create e new one. Deleted a project and created a new one.
2. Preferences > Locations > Derived Data > click the arrow to open in Finder > trash it.
   But It did not help me. Can you explain me please how to do it.

[image]

Comment: Note the line above the work area: ***An internal error occurred. Editing functionality may be limited.*** -- close and restart Xcode ... if that doesn't fix it, try deleting your Main.storyboard and creating a new one ... if that still doesn't fix it, try restarting your system.

Comment: I deleted storyboard, then deleted a project and made a new one, but anyway the background is not changing

Comment: As long as that error message is there, you'll have problems. Did none of those options fix it?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was because I work on a new Macbook M1. And usually I deal with React Native projects, therefore I launched XCode only with rosetta 2, because the current versions of RN projects is not building there. After usual launch with out rosetta 2 the error and black background has disappeared.